# UITabBarItem - Background color in iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar, uitabbaritem, ios9

I am trying to change background color of my UITabBarItem this way:

```
UITabBar.appearance().selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(UIColor.blackColor())
```

Here's `extension` for `UIImage`:

```
extension UIImage {
    class func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image
    }
}
```

It does not work. Here's how it should look finally:[image]

Comment: why dont you just use UITabBar.appearance().tintColor property ?

Comment: I am setting tint to white color, and I need to set background color to black. See updated question.

Comment: @NikitaZernov Any update about my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your image is too small `let rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)`. Try to replace with `let rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 50.0)`.